# regular expressions escaping rules- Perl-compatible regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, escaping

why in the following code, in order to match the string, then we have to escape the '$' with two backslashes and not one?

```
<?php
$text = "$3.99";
preg_match_all("/\\$\d+\.\d{2}/", $text, $matches) ;
var_dump($matches) ;
?>

output: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '$3.99' (length=5)
```

what is the matching rule for the pattern: "/\$\d+.\d{2}/" (one backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

From the docs

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters:

Then

```
\\  backslash
\$  dollar sign
```

So the double backslash is for the string not the regex

A single backslash would result in the $ literal which is then passed to the regex

Comment: can you give me an example for a match: preg_match("/\$\d+\.\d{2}/" , "______")

Comment: I understood what you are saying. that the $ is a special character in regex so if I will write "/\$/" it will mean /$/ . but what does the $ special character does if it is written there and not at the end of the pattern? can you find a subject that will match the pattern in my comment above?

Comment: it means match the end of the string and then match some stuff after it. Which will not work. Either switch to single strings or escape your backslash. Its the backslash causing the issue really

Answer (score 0):

I think php has a few options for depicting the regex string.
At the first level, they seem to want strings of some sort because
they don't have quote like operators like Perl, at least I don't think so.

Level 2, they move on to the regex delimiter (stay away from double quotes as delimiter).

Level 3, the raw regex is left bare after 1 & 2 are done.

So usually, you have reverse the process 3 - 2 -1, and present that to the php source code.

A note - Regex delimiters are a tricky business. In level 2, it is possible that you could
choose a delimiter that is un-escapable in the regular expression. In your case '`$`' would
not be a viable delimiter.

Some possibilities might help you...

```
\$\d+\.\d{2}                 # raw regex

/\$\d+\.\d{2}/               # no quote, using '/' for delimeter
'/\$\d+\.\d{2}/'             # single quotes        ""
"/\\$\\d+\\.\\d{2}/"         # double quotes        ""

~\$\d+\.\d{2}~                # no quote, using '~' for delimeter
'~\$\d+\.\d{2}~'              # single quotes        ""
"~\\$\\d+\\.\\d{2}~"          # double quotes        ""
```